# Error al mandar query en GraphQL con vue y apollo

Tags: vue.js, graphql

tengo un código en el que necesito sacar una lista con distintas pelis de star wars, en la query que tengo en el siguiente archivo `MoviesList.vue` me funciona directamente en el siguiente enlace: https://movie-database-graphql.herokuapp.com/graphiql no sé si estoy recogiendo los datos mal o no, pero la query me funciona en el enlace. Dejo los archivos:

Error:

```
Error sending the query 'movies' ServerParseError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/apollo-link-http-common/lib/bundle.esm.js:46:
```

MoviesList.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <movie-item v-for="movie in movies" :key="movie.id" :movie="movie"></movie-item>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MovieItem from "./MovieItem";
import gql from "graphql-tag";

const GET_MOVIES = gql`
  query StarWars {
    movies(query: "Star Wars") {
      id
      poster_path
      title
      overview
    }
  }
`;

export default {
  name: "MoviesList",
  components: { MovieItem },
  data() {
    return {
      movies: []
    };
  },
  apollo: {
    movies: {
      query: GET_MOVIES
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

MovieItem.vue:

```
<template>
  <div :key="movie.id">
    <h3>{{ movie.title }}</h3>
    <p>{{ movie.overview }}</p>
    <p>{{ movie.poster_path }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "MovieItem",
  props: ["movie"]
};
</script>
```

Comment: Podes aclarar mejor cual es el problema?

Comment: Sí, perdona, acabo de añadir la linea de error. @gbianchi

Comment: Y como es el json que mandas?

Comment: @gbianchi El json que mando lo puedes ejecutar tal cual aqui, que lo cojo del enlace. Al ejecutar la query sale el json, o lo tengo que poner en algun archivo aparte? https://movie-database-graphql.herokuapp.com/graphiql

Comment: No termino de entender que queres hacer. Agarras el json de un enlance, y que queres hacer con el?

Comment: Hacer una consulta al json para obtener la lista de peliculas y poner esos datos como informacion, como si fuese una cartelera, @gbianchi